# Django - filter two M2M fields to one model for specifis condition happening in single object

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

The problem that I am facing is quite complicated but maybe the answer is simple. So I have a model with two M2M fields to the same model, and I want to filter only these objects which are in 1st field but are not in 2nd.

```py
class Model1(models.Model):
    ...


class Model2(models.Model):
    rel1 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Model1,
        related_name="rel1"
    )
    rel2 = models.ManyToManyField(
        Model1,
        related_name="rel2"
    )
```

and now I want to get objects which for single `Model2` objects are only in `rel1` not in `rel2`.
For example

```py
obj2_1 = Model2(rel1=[obj1, obj2, obj3], rel2=[obj1, obj2])
obj2_2 = Model2(rel1=[obj1, obj3], rel2=[obj1, obj2, obj3])

Model1.objects.filter_that_i_am_looking_for() -> obj3
```

where object1,2,3 are Model1 instances and obj2_1, obj2_2 are Model2 instances. Note that obj3 is a result even tho it is in obj2_2 rel2!

I would like to get database query, not getting all objects and then making some python filter on that. I am expecting to get some annotation or something similar.

Comment: so are you looking for `obj2_1`, or `obj3`?

Comment: I am looking for `obj3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [**`.filter(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#filter) and  [**`.exclude(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#exclude) in an [**`Exists`** subquery <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Model1.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        Model2.objects.filter(rel1=OuterRef('pk')).exclude(
            rel2=OuterRef('pk')
        )
    )
)
```

We thus return `Model1` objects given there exists (at least one) `Model2` object where that item appears in the `rel1` relation, and not in the `rel2` relation.